# How to render if..else if...else type in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React hooks and following is the conditional rendering which I want to achieve where `sortDirection` is a state. I want to render one of the `<i>` tag based on `sortDirection`. How can I achieve this ?

```
    if (sortDirection == "ascending") {
        return <i onclick={() => setSortDirection('descending')} className="fa fa-arrow-down" />
    } else if (sortDirection == "descending") {
        return <i onClick={() => setSortDirection('random')} className="fa fa-arrow-up" />
    } else {
        return <i onClick={() => setSortDirection('ascending')} className="fa fa-arrow-h" />
    }
```

Comment: React hooks don't change anything that would apply to the code you're showing. That code would look no different for a function component.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? What you've done seems to already answer your question unless I'm not understanding you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a separate functional component and having the condition as a prop

```
const MyIComponent = (sortDirection) => {
  if (sortDirection == "ascending") {
        return <i onclick={() => setSortDirection('descending')} className="fa fa-arrow-down" />
    } else if (sortDirection == "descending") {
        return <i onClick={() => setSortDirection('random')} className="fa fa-arrow-up" />  }

    return <i onClick={() => setSortDirection('ascending')} className="fa fa-arrow-h" />
}

const MainComponent = () => <myIComponent sortDirection={sortDirection} />
```

Comment: Rather than creating a separate component I just created a const DirectionIcon = {the above conditional render} and in return wrote <DirectionIcon /> . As in your comment you defined myIComponent I think the first letter should be capital for react to recognize it as a React component. Apart form that all went good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyIComponent = ({sortDirection, iClassName}) => {
  return <i onclick={() => setSortDirection(sortDirection)} className={iClassName} />
}
```

You can pass `sortDirection` and `iClassName` dynamically from main component as a props then if conditions also you can avoid.

Comment: const myIComponent = ({sortDirection, iClassName}) => {
  return <i onclick={() => setSortDirection(sortDirection)} className={iClassName} />
}